# How to send packets from outside world IP to Pod as i am receiving from pod to outside world IP

Tags: kubernetes

How to send packets from outside world IP to Pod as i am receiving from pod to outside world IP?

`service.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1  
kind: Service  
metadata:  
  name: gnb-service  
spec:      
  selector:  
    app: 5ggnb   
    type: ClusterIP  
  ports:
    port: 58242  
    name: 5gsvc  
    protocol: UDP  
      targetPort: 58242   
externalIPs:  
  198.168.11.188 # Node1-IP
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1  
kind: Endpoints  
  metadata:    
    name: gnb-endpoints  
  subsets:  
   addresses:  
     - ip: 192.168.30.61  
  ports:  
   port: 58242  
     protocol: UDP'
```

Comment: You'll need ingress to reach your pod if that what you are looking for

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to expose a Pod to clients outside your cluster SDN is to use Ingress Controllers (haproxy, nginx, traefik, ....). There may already be one of those deployed in your cluster, at which point you would create an Ingress object.

Another way to do this would be to user a Service with type=NodePort. Although this is usually not recommended - production Kubernetes clusters would rarely allow direct connections to such ports: ensuring Ingresses are the only point of entry to applications is one of the first steps to Kubernetes clusters hardening.

In clusters that are integrated with a cloud provider (aws, azure, openstack, ...), and clusters including some MetalLB deployment, you may be able to use a Service with type=LoadBalancer.

Do not set one of your node IP address as externalIPs on a Service.

Comment: can u suggest me with example and the ip which is set as external ip is not an node ip

Comment: externalIP would be set by provisioning a loadbalancer service. matching the address assigned to you. or metallb in bare-metal. We could set an externalIP arbitrarily, although that's really not something I would recommend, not knowing of your context. Please elaborate, why is it Ingresses, or eventually LoadBalancers services, would not suit your use case. Don't set externalIPs randomly, it just won't work, it requires some prior configuration of the networking / LAN routing configuration..